# Filling a hierarchical HDF5 dataset in a loop

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

What I am trying to do is take an existing HDF5 hierarchical dataset, select some of the elements, do an operation on them, and create a transformed file.

To read the file and do the operations, I am using a similar code

```py
import h5py

with h5py.File(path, 'r') as fDFT:  # Loads the dataset and closes the file after the loop
        mol_ids = list(fDFT.keys()) # Main identifier of the data
        for molid in mol_ids: # Iterate over each data
                conf_ids = list( fDFT[molid].keys() ) 
                for confid in conf_ids: # Iterate over the configurations
                    if 'opt' in str( confid ): # Only select specific configurations
                        res1 = fDFT[molid][confid]['mPOL'][:] # Read an entry from the file
                        res2 = convert(fDFT[molid][confid]['atNUM'][:]) # Transform another entry
```

I can create the output HDF5 file and write the first identifier easily, since mol_ids is a variable saved, by adding

```py
hdf5_output = h5py.File('restricted.hdf5','w')
hdf5_output['molid']=mol_ids
```

but this creates a label 'molid', which is not what I want (the labels should be the values within molid), and I am not sure how to extend this approach to the nested level anyways.

Is there a nice way to get a HDF5 file that follows the hierarchy of the for loop, that is, would create a data structure that can be called as `hdf5_output[molid][confid]['mPOL']` for example?

I've tried the create_group() function, but this did not allow me to iteratively create a group.

Comment: What prevent you from iteratively create groups with create_group() ? Show your code and explain what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the string `'molid'` with the variable name `molid`. Also, you need to create a group with the name. Likely you want is: `hdf5_output.create_group(molid)` (group name w/out quotes). As I understand your 2nd question, it would look something like this.

```
# Opens the source dataset for reading and
# creates the restricted dataset for writing
# Closes the file when exiting the with/as context manager
with h5py.File(path, 'r') as fDFT, \
     h5py.File('restricted.hdf5','w') as hdf5_output:

    for molid in fDFT: # Iterate over root level objects
        # Create a group named molid in 2nd H5 file:
        hdf5_output.create_group(molid)
        for confid in fDFT[molid]: # Iterate over the configuration datasets
            if 'opt' in confid: # Select configurations with 'opt' in dataset name
                res1 = fDFT[molid][confid]['mPOL'][()] # Read an entry from the file
                res2 = convert(fDFT[molid][confid]['atNUM'][()]) # Transform another entry
                # The following code is my guess at the 2nd part (writing res/res2 data to the new file)
                # This uses the h5py group.copy method to copy the res1 dataset - won't work for res2: 
                # It is the easiest/preferred way to copy datasets as-is
                fDFT.copy(fDFT[molid][confid]['mPOL'], hdf5_output[molid][confid]) 

                # This writes your res1 and res2 arrays to the new file                    hdf5_output[molid][confid]['mPOL'] = res1    
                hdf5_output[molid][confid]['mPOL'] = res1  
                hdf5_output[molid][confid]['atNUM_converted'] = res2  

                # Alternately, you could do this, and skip res1/res2 creation
                hdf5_output[molid][confid]['mPOL'] = fDFT[molid][confid]['mPOL'][()]   
                hdf5_output[molid][confid]['atNUM_converted'] = convert(fDFT[molid][confid]['atNUM'][()])
```

Notes:

- I took the liberty to simplify the code by removing extraneous lines.
- I combined file open operations into a single `with/as` context manager
- You don't need `.keys()` to get the object names. Similar to dictionary syntax, a loop on an H5 object will yield the keys (group and/or dataset names). Also, you don't need to convert to a list.
- The h5py `group.copy()` method is the simplest way to copy an entire dataset as-is. By default it uses source dataset compression and chunking parameters and copies attributes. I included an example for the `'mPOL'` dataset. Complete description [here](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html#h5py.Group.copy).
- Preferred way to extract the entire dataset as a NumPy array is `ds_name[()]` instead of `ds_name[:]`. Ref: [h5py Reading & writing data](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data)